# Supersize jQuery plugin not loading images in IE7 IE8

Tags: jquery

Please note: I have tried the removing the comma from last image filepath fix that new users commonly have problems with. It has not solved my problem.

My site using the Supersize jQuery plugin is not loading images in IE7 and IE8. It works fine everywhere else in all browsers. I have noticed that using the IE Debug Toolbar to force quirks mode for IE8 makes it load the images, just as it's supposed to. What I get in IE7/IE8 is a gray screen and the image loader anim and no error messages that I can detect with Firebug nor the IE Debug Toolbar. I am using it in a Wordpress site but not the Wordpress plugin, rather I am using the jQuery plugin instead. My Supersize code is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(function($){

            $.supersized({

                // Functionality
                slide_interval          :   4000,       // Length between transitions
                transition              :   1,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed        :   700,        // Speed of transition

                // Components                           
                slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                                                    {image : 'http://boultonweb.com/dennis-sparrow/wp-content/themes/SDMTheme/superstuff/slides/Donnie-S_Home_Duo_NAME.jpg'},
                                                    {image : 'http://boultonweb.com/dennis-sparrow/wp-content/themes/SDMTheme/superstuff/slides/Tom-M_Home_Duo_NAME.jpg'},                                                      
                                                    {image : 'http://boultonweb.com/dennis-sparrow/wp-content/themes/SDMTheme/superstuff/slides/Jason-S_Home_Duo_NAME.jpg'},
                                                    {image : 'http://boultonweb.com/dennis-sparrow/wp-content/themes/SDMTheme/superstuff/slides/James-G_Home_Duo_NAME.jpg'},                                                        
                                                    {image : 'http://boultonweb.com/dennis-sparrow/wp-content/themes/SDMTheme/superstuff/slides/RDJoseph_Home_Duo_NAME-3.jpg'},
                                                    {image : 'http://boultonweb.com/dennis-sparrow/wp-content/themes/SDMTheme/superstuff/slides/Paul-D_Home_Duo_NAME.jpg'},
                                                    {image : 'http://boultonweb.com/dennis-sparrow/wp-content/themes/SDMTheme/superstuff/slides/Steven-H_Home_Duo_NAME.jpg'},
                                                    {image : 'http://boultonweb.com/dennis-sparrow/wp-content/themes/SDMTheme/superstuff/slides/JMTHomas_Home_Duo_NAME.jpg'}                                                    
                                            ]                                           

            });
            if(window.innerWidth <= 765){
                all_slides = [ all_slides.shift() ];
            }else{
                //only need controllers for multiple slides
                $("#slider article:first-child").addClass('active');
            }

        });

    </script>
```

Does anyone see any of my novice errors that might be preventing this from running in IE7 and IE8 or have troubleshooting suggestions or even a workaround? I have been validating html5/css removing errors but this has has no tangible effect so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-c-

Answer (score 0):

IE7 & IE8 do not support `window.innerWidth`, use jQuery `$(window).innerWidth()`

Comment: Roland Jensen - thanks for the quick response. Where am I using "window.innerWidth"? I just searched all my js and css files with Find/Replace tool and turned up no instances of "window.innerWidth" Sorry, noob here and your help is appreciated.

Tate Reynolds - the first line of my request for help AND the code I posted show that it's not the comma after the filepath problem. I copied my code out of the provided demo and am using the same scripts. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: `if(window.innerWidth <= 765){` is in your question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Roland but no dice. Was worth a try. I also removed a mobile detection script that was using "window.innerWidth" and replaced it with a user-agent sniffer so that there were no instances of "window.innerWidth" in the entire site but no luck. I am having to test with IE Tester (for IE7/8) and am uncertain if that is giving me accurate feedback. Anyone have IE7/IE8 still installed or running on a VM? The url is http://sparrowdennis.com/. Anticapated result is gray screen with perpetual loading anim. Thanks again Roland.

Comment: Roland, I tried that and removed all instances of "window.innerWidth" as suggested without any luck. I did however comment out the following from my Wordpress header.php:
    <!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->

and now it's working in IE7 and IE8. I guess browsers will not understand the html5 shim in the WP install? Uncertain here. More stuff to research! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Crap. I thought I had a solution but I didn't. The testing tool I was using, IE Tester, led me to believe that I had fixed the problem but Supersized still shows only gray block instead of pictures in IE 8. Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

The supersized demo works perfectly in IE - http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/3/default.html

If you read a little more on the supersized jquery plugin - http://buildinternet.com/2010/11/supersized-3-0-full-screen-background-slideshow-jquery-plugin/

Also be sure that you have the latest jquery plugin...

Someone else came across the same issue with a missing comma after a closing tag:

```
<script type=&#34;text/javascript&#34;>  
    $&#40;function&#40;&#41;{
        $.fn.supersized.options = {  
            startwidth&#58; 640,  
            startheight&#58; 480,
            vertical_center&#58; 1,
            slideshow&#58; 1,
            navigation&#58; 0,
            thumbnail_navigation&#58; 0,
            transition&#58; 1, //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-slide top, 3-slide right, 4-slide bottom, 5-slide left
            pause_hover&#58; 0,
            slide_counter&#58; 0,
            slide_captions&#58; 0,
            slide_interval&#58; 15000,
            slides &#58; &#91;
                {image &#58; &#39;slides/background_3.jpg&#39;, title &#58; &#39;City Clock Tower&#39;},
                {image &#58; &#39;slides/background_1.jpg&#39;, title &#58; &#39;City Clock Tower&#39;},
                {image &#58; &#39;slides/background_2.jpg&#39;, title &#58; &#39;City Clock Tower&#39;},
                {image &#58; &#39;slides/background_4.jpg&#39;, title &#58; &#39;City Clock Tower&#39;}
            &#93;
        };
        $&#40;&#39;#supersized&#39;&#41;.supersized&#40;&#41;; 
    }&#41;;
</script>
```